# Spark adding indexes to dataframe and append other dataset that doesn't have index

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset that has column userid and index values.

```
+---------+--------+
|  userid |   index|
+---------+--------+
|    user1|       1|
|    user2|       2|
|    user3|       3|
|    user4|       4|
|    user5|       5|
|    user6|       6|
|    user7|       7|
|    user8|       8|
|    user9|       9|
|   user10|      10|
+---------+--------+
```

I want to append a new data frame to it and add an index to the newly added columns.
The `userid` is unique and the existing data frame will not have the Dataframe 2 user ids.

```
+----------+
|  userid  |
+----------+
|    user11|
|    user21| 
|    user41| 
|    user51| 
|    user64|
+----------+
```

The expected output with newly added `userid` and index

```
+---------+--------+
|  userid |   index|
+---------+--------+
|    user1|        1|
|    user2|        2|
|    user3|        3|
|    user4|        4|
|    user5|        5|
|    user6|        6|
|    user7|        7|
|    user8|        8|
|    user9|        9|
|    user10|      10|
|    user11|      11|
|    user21|      12| 
|    user41|      13| 
|    user51|      14| 
|    user64|      15|
+---------+--------+
```

Is it possible to achive this by passing a max index value and start index for second Dataframe from given index value.

Comment: did you get a chance to try out the answer? did it work for you?

Comment: Hi Raghu, yes I got a chance but decided to use a different approach as the second dataset is smaller and may not require  window partitioning on `df_merge`

Answer (score 1):

If the userid has some ordering, then you can use the rownumber function. Even if it does not have, then you can add an id using monotonically_increasing_id(). For now I assume that userid can be ordered. Then you can do this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
df_merge = df1.select('userid').union(df2.select('userid'))
w=Window.orderBy('userid')
df_result = df_merge.withColumn('indexid',F.row_number().over(w))
```

**EDIT :** After discussions in comment.

```
#%% Test data and imports
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('a',100),('ab',50),('ba',300),('ced',60),('d',500)],schema=['userid','index'])
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('fgh',100),('ff',50),('fe',300),('er',60),('fi',500)],schema=['userid','dummy'])
#%%

#%% Merge the two dataframes, with a null columns as the index
df1=df1.withColumn('index', F.lit(None))
df_merge = df.select(df.columns).union(df1.select(df.columns))
#%%Define a window to arrange the newly added rows at the last and order them by userid
#%% The user id, even though random strings, can be ordered
w= Window.orderBy(F.col('index').asc_nulls_last(),F.col('userid'))# if possible add a partition column here, otherwise all your data will come in one partition, consider salting
#%% For the newly added rows, define index as the maximum value + increment of number of rows in main dataframe
df_final = df_merge.withColumn("index_new",F.when(~F.col('index').isNull(),F.col('index')).otherwise((F.last(F.col('index'),ignorenulls=True).over(w))+F.sum(F.lit(1)).over(w)))
#%% If number of rows in main dataframe is huge, then add an offset in the above line

df_final.show()
+------+-----+---------+
|userid|index|index_new|
+------+-----+---------+
|    ab|   50|       50|
|   ced|   60|       60|
|     a|  100|      100|
|    ba|  300|      300|
|     d|  500|      500|
|    er| null|      506|
|    fe| null|      507|
|    ff| null|      508|
|   fgh| null|      509|
|    fi| null|      510|
+------+-----+---------+
```

Comment: userids are not ordered. also, there are billion of ids in data frame one for which the existing index can not be changed.

Comment: are the existing ids continuously numbered as shown in the input?

Comment: should the new user id increase by 1 , or can it be random but just unique? and are you looking only for scala solutions?

Comment: yes, I prefer it is increased by 1 not the just random number.
I use Scala but python also works